# RSA Reverse Encryption using Certificate

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, rsa, x509certificate

I am using certificate to encrypt my communication between WCF and Android. Encrypting using Public Key, and decrypting with Private Key is working fine. But I return a session ID from the WCF Application to the Android Client. Now, I need to encrypt the SessionID using my Private Key and Encrypt at the client side using Public Key (Reverse). This reverse encryption and decryption is working fine in the Android Test. But in my C# Test, decryption shows error "Key doesn't exist". I tried changing the encoding to all the possible ones, but no hope. Here is the code.

```
    private void Encrypt()
    {

        X509Certificate2 myCert2 = null;
        myCert2 = new X509Certificate2(Resource1.code, "code");
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCert2.PrivateKey;

        string strtt = "This is a test"; 
        byte[] ascenc = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(strtt);
        encrbyte = RSA.Encrypt(ascenc, false);
        encrypted_string =Convert.ToBase64String(encrbyte);
        textBox2.Text = encrypted_string;


    }

    private void Decrypt()
    {

        var myCert2 = new X509Certificate2(Resource1.code, "code");
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCert2.PublicKey.Key;
        byte[] ascby = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted_string);
        byte[] decrypted_byte = RSA.Decrypt(ascby, false);
        string decrypted_text = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(decrypted_byte);
        textBox3.Text = decrypted_text; 

    }
```

Comment: Please show the real error you get, and what line it applies to.

Comment: RSA.Decrypt(ascby, false);
shows  "Key doesn't exist"

Comment: There is no such thing as RSA reverse encryption. You should encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key. If you really need to (but why) you should take a look at signatures with (partial) message recovery. But many of these schemes have been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question reads, "Now, I need to **encrypt** the SessionID using my Private Key and **Encrypt** at the client side using Public Key (Reverse)" -- did you mean *decrypt* with the public key?

Do you realize that if you encrypt with the private key, *anybody* can decrypt that has seen the certificate, i.e. anybody who has the public key?

Comment: But How can I send back the sessionID to the Client ? There is no meaning sending in plain text or using symmetric encryption

Comment: Without knowing the specifics I would *guess* that you would want to let the client generate a random symmetric key, encrypt this using the public key, let the server decrypt it and use the symmetric key to encrypt whatever you want to send back to the client. Hybrid encryption.

Comment: Exactly what @clausc writes: the client can generate a cryptographically strong random key, say 128-bits (16 bytes), encrypt this with the server's public key (RSA most likely, using OAEP padding) and send it to the server, who decrypts it with the server's private key. Can you use TLS? It's much safer to use the well-worn path and not invent your own crypto.